# rspec controller builds multiple records in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I have a rails app that has an account signup form, that at the same time as creating the account also creates an admin user as well.

The controller code for the new method is a simple

```
  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.users.build
  end
```

In the create method the two models are validated and created in the following way

```
  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    @account.status = "signup"
    if @account.save
      #find the user
      user = User.where("account_id =?", @account.id).first
      role = Role.where("rolesymbol =?", "admin").first
      @authorization = Authorization.new
      @authorization.role_id = role.id
      @authorization.user_id = user.id
      @authorization.save
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
```

In practice this all works well. However, I can't figure out how to build the user in an rspec controller test. I have tried things on the lines of

```
  describe "POST 'create'" do
    it "should create if all the details are correct" do
      account_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:account)
      user_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user)
      post :create, :account => account_params, ;user => user_params
    end
```

However, this, as the code shows, just puts the two models in sequence rather than having user as part of account.

Has anyone done anything similar?

Comment: Could you add to your spec what you're expecting to see as a result? Thanks.

Comment: I can see I missed that as I am just looking for a success in the first instance. Because I don't have the user built correctly the create method fails at the controller level, and so I am not even at the stage of testing results

Comment: I can't understand where you create user.
In action `new` user is built (not created) then in action `create` account is saved and you try to find user. But no user has been created yet. Code `user = User.where...` returns nil and you get `nil.id`.

Comment: Is user being created via `accepts_nested_attributes` in Account? And are you asking for help with the controller or the spec? I'm confused.

Comment: In the form I have attributes for the account and for the user. And sorry yes there is accepts_nested_attributes in the model. So I'm asking help with the spec, how do I get the spec to create both the account and user. If I just send the account params in the spec create I get an error about missing user attributes, so need to work out how to get them both created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I worked this out. So in the controller spec for a model that builds two models in a form.

the controller spec could should be

```
post :create, :account => attributes_for(:account).merge(users_attributes: [ attributes_for(:user) ])
  response.should redirect_to "http://test.host/subscribe/subcode/1/user-2"
```

Sorry for the earlier poor description of where the error was, but hope this helps anyone else with the same issue